# firebase JS not able to Add firstname lastname after auth

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Im working with react-native redux app. This is my newly created firebase database.

Everything is working fine, user is able to sign in and Sign-Up as well. But I have this little code after sign-up I'm trying `.set({ firstname, lastname })` firstname, lastname which does not reflect in database. (github repo: https://github.com/steelx/react-native-redux-app)

```
    export const signUpUser = ({ firstname = "", lastname = "", email, password }) => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: SIGN_UP_REQUEST });

    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((user) => {

            // const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
            // currentUser.updateProfile({
            //     displayName: `${firstname} ${lastname}`,
            //     THIS WORKS
            // })

            firebase.database().ref('users/' + user.uid)
            // THIS DOES NOT WORK
                .set({ "firstname": 'AJINKYA', "lastname": 'AJINKYA' })
                .then(() => {
                    dispatch({ type: SIGN_UP_SUCCESS, payload: user });
                    Actions.home();
                });
        })
        .catch((error) => { dispatch({ type: SIGN_UP_FAILURE, payload: authFailMessage(error.code) }); });
};
```

**Firebase rules**

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What are `firstname` and `lastname` in here?

Comment: "test", "test" `String`

Comment: what I found was I can set only `displayName`. This works fine ==> firebase.auth().currentUser.updateProfile({displayName: `${firstname} ${lastname}`})

But my question still remains, what if I want add entry in database.

Comment: Cool. Can you see if you can reproduce it when you hardcode those values into `set`, so `.set({ firstname: "test", lastname: "test" })`. If that still reproduces it, we can rule out scope problems with the variables.

Comment: I did this `.set({ "firstname": 'AJINKYA', "lastname": 'AJINKYA' })`, still no use

Comment: Hmmm... it might be a permissions issue. Can you add a `catch` to the `set` and log any error. So `.set({ "firstname": 'AJINKYA', "lastname": 'AJINKYA' }).catch((error) => { console.error(error); }).then(...`

Comment: `{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry my bad I was passing `uid` as `undefined` at ref. and originally before posting this question the RULES were set to Locked.

and my rules were also wrong. Later I updated rules to =>
as a quick fix I added these rules. Everything works fine now.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```